# Find the area enclosed by the graphs of $y = -x^2 + 4x + 8$ and $y = x^2 - 2x$ from $x = -1$ to $x = 4$

Tags: calculus

I know that when you set up the integral the lower boundary will be -1 and the upper boundary will be 4.

Would you set up the integral as such:

$$\int^4_{-1} \bigl((-x^2+4x+8)-(x^2-2x)\bigr)\,dx$$

When I do this and solve, I get the area as $125/3$.

Comment: It would be helpful to make a graph before putting the functions blindly in some formula.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equations, you will get that the points of intersection are $ (-1,3)$ and $(4,8)$.

[image: check it!!]

So the required area will be $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^4 \{(-x^2+4x+8)-(x^2-2x)\}\,dx$